# Choropleth world map not showing all countries

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I wanted to make a choropleth world map, which shows the hits(number of searches) of a word, on a World map.

Following is the code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('F:\\Intern\\csir\\1yr\\news\\region_2016_2017.xlsx') 
df = df.query('keyword==["addiction"]')
scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
            [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]
data = [dict(
                type='choropleth',
                colorscale=scl,

                locations = df['location'],
                z = df['hits'].astype(int),
                locationmode = "country names",
                autocolorscale = False,
                reversescale = False,
                marker = dict(
                                line = dict (
                                    color = 'rgb(180,180,180)',
                                    width = 0.5)),
                                colorbar = dict(
                                    autotick = False,

                                    title = 'Hits'),)]

layout = dict(
    title = 'Addiction keyword 1yr analysis',
    geo = dict(
        showframe = False,
        showcoastlines = False,
        projection = dict(
            type = 'Mercator'
        )

    )       
)
fig = dict(data = data,layout = layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig,validate=False,filename = 'd3-world-map.html')
```

And the plotted map is:
[image]

As one can see clearly, many countries are missing. This may be due to the fact that many countries didn't have entries which explicitly stated that they have zero hits.

I don't want to explicitly do that with my data. Is there any other way out of this? So that we can see all of the countries.

---

Data set can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxW1cRdnY7wmUHhBWjNoemxzY1U).

---

Note that the dataset that I've linked is an `.csv` file whereas the file used in the program is an  `.xlsx` version of the file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn on country outlines under layout...

```
"geo":{
    "countriescolor": "#444444",
    "showcountries": true
},
```